# Use ScrollTo() on newly opened page

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am trying to figure out a way to use the `scrollTo()` function on a new page after a link has been clicked.  Unfortunately, using `window.onload` won't work in my situation since I only want to scroll if the page is opened from a particular link.

I'm trying to get the home page to link and scroll to the 'other' section of the services page:

**HTML:**

`<a onclick="otherServices">Other Services</a>`

**JavaScript:**

```
function otherServices() {
    window.location = "/services";
    win = window.location;
    setTimeout(win.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight), 3000);
}
```

Preferably I would like to avoid using jQuery if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work. Fires on load and looks if it's on the services page, then scrolls "somewhere" (fill in the blanks! "somewhere" is the position of your "other" section).

**On the homepage:**
`<a href="/services">Other Services</a>`

**On the services page:**

```js
window.onload = function () {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/services') {
    window.scrollTo(0, somewhere)
  }
}
```

**Update: misunderstood the problem, better solution:**

**On the homepage:**
`<a href="/services#section-id">Other Services</a>`

**On the services page:**
`<section id="section-id">Other Services</section>`

The browser will do the work for you.

Comment: I am not trying to call the scroll function if the page is the services page, I am only trying to call the scroll function if the services page has been opened from a SPECIFIC link on the home page.

Comment: Then your link should probably append a query string like `/services?ref=foo-bar` that you can test for.

Comment: @klaemo or when he clicks the link, he can set something in localstorage and check it in onload function, so the url will be clear

Answer (score 2):

from a particular link on the homepage you could use `hash`.

**homepage link**

```
<a href="/services#scroll">Other Services</a>
```

**services js**

```
window.onload = function () {
  if (window.location.hash == '#scroll') {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
  }
}
```

Or you could do it without JS, but setting the hash in the link to the `Id` of the element you want to scroll too.

Comment: the hash and id version would probably be the most standard and clean solution.